# Text box in td losing value when div is disabled

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have a JavaScript function DisableDuedate() that disables a td tag based on the logged in user. 
The td tag contains a text box that is populated on Page_load (vb code behind page).
The DisableDueDate() function is called in the HTML page

```
<body onload='scrollBar(null,null,"red");' onload='DisableDueDate();'>
```

The function is defined in the head tag

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

            function DisableDueDate()
            {
                var udisable = '<%=dueDateDisabled %>';
                                                        if (udisable == "true")
                    document.getElementById("divduedate").setAttribute('disabled',true);
                else
                    document.getElementById("divduedate").setAttribute('disabled',false);

            }
    </script>
```

This works fine but the value of the textbox that is in the td tag is displaying 0 when the div tag is disabled.
How to retain the text box value when the enclosing div tag is disabled ?

Comment: There isn't a disabled attribute for div elements. There is for fieldset (and browsers are supposed to disable form controls that are descendants of disabled fieldsets). You are probably running into error recovery and the browser is treating the div as a fieldset. Try sticking to valid HTML. Don't disable the div — it makes no sense to.

Comment: Please be aware that internet explorer inherits and nests the disabled attribute.

Answer (score 0):

You would probably want to save the value of the text box let's say in an html attribute tag on the `<div data-value="put it here">`, or in `$.data()` if you're using jQuery.

Then simply when enabling it, check to see if data-value exists, if so put it in the textboxes value.  Simple enough!

Comment: SORRY! The textbox is in a td tag and not a div tag

Comment: Yes! The textbox does have a vlue just before the td is disabled.